# Is it possible to use ExpandoObject with EFCore?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, expandoobject

I am supposed to store in a database, objects with dynamic properties, which can only be determined at runtime.

I found the [ExpandoObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?view=net-6.0) class which might be something that I can use for this, but I am not sure how/if I can store the properties of this such object with Efcore.

Did someone managed to do it?

Comment: You will need to create json/varchar field in your database and possibly add converter which will serialize/deserialize data.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: Short answer: no.